# .htacces folder name with same file name?

Tags: .htaccess, web, feed, article

I have a file in my webpage called news.
I did not write .html the end of the file, is this still correct? (the browser shows like html) 
I want to make a folder in my server with the same name and put the articles there.

For example:
www.example.com/news ->>> this shows the main news page
www.example.com/news/article0101 --> this shows the article

If a user type www.example.com/news or www.example.com/news/ both must show the main news page.
In my webserver, I made all files without any extension.

I have read previous Q/A -s from this page and other pages and I have did not found a valid soulution to my problem? 
Can I even modify the .htacces file in this way? Or I approach the problem in the wrong way?

Do I require a database or I just need files if I want to write articles?
Where can I find standard documentation for a webpage with articles and news?

Thanks very much your help

Comment: One more to add: the folder news and the file news should be the same name in my webserver

Comment: you can enable multiviews, create a directory /news/ with an index.html, and a directory /news/article0101, with a index.html in it.